# getting value from Form1 and pass to Form2 Java JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jspinner

I have 2 `Java` files (both JFrame Forms).
I have a `JSpinner` and a  `text-area` in Form1.

In the `spinner` I define the `font-size` of the `text-area`'s- text.

In `Form2` I have a `Button` and also a `Text-area`.

*What I want to do:*

**I change the `Text-area`'s `font-size` in Form1's `spinner`.
In `Form2` when I click on the `button`, I want the text inside the Form2's `Text-Area` to be the same size as defined in Form1's `spinner`.**

I have the necesarry `setters` and `getters` (for the `spinner's` value and to change the size of the Fonts)
My problem is:

I create a new `Form` in `form2` in order to reach the methods.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.setFontSize(form2.getJSpinnerValue());
```

It returns the minimum '1' value even if I change the size... 
I suppose that this is because I create a new `Form`..

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a constructor in Form1:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(getSpinnerValue());
```

In Form2:

```
private int fontsize;
public Form2(int spinnerValue){
initcomponents();
this.fontsize=spinnerValue;
}

private void jBtFontsizeChanger()
{
jTextArea.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,fontsize));
 }
```